# how do I get bash globbing to work in script

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I am trying to convert some of my ksh93 scripts to bash in cygwin. I have found 2 things right now that give me trouble. The first is a function I put in .bashrc was not recognized in the script. I put the function in the script to get around that. The second is that it won't glob like it does in ksh93. Setting `extglob` didn't seem to help.  Here is what I have done:

```
#! /bin/bash

rep() {
        perl -E 'say "'"$1"'" x '$2
        # seq -s"$1" $2|tr -d '[:digit:]'
}

# added these 2 lines for testing
shopt -s extglob
shopt extglob

ziptext="Monthly files for $(date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +'%B %Y')"
equals4=$(rep = $((${#ziptext} + 6)))
equals="$(rep = ${#ziptext})"
spaces="$(rep ' ' ${#ziptext})"

# added these 2 lines for testing
ls -l 20[0-9][0-9]' Monthly Data - review.xlsx'
pwd

echo "

  $equals4
  =  $equals  =
  =  $spaces  =
  =  $ziptext  =
  =  $spaces  =
  =  $equals  =
  $equals4\n\n\n" | zip -9 -u -z \
        20[0-9][0-9]' Monthly Data - review.xlsx' \
        20[0-9][0-9]' Monthly Tables - review.xlsx'
```

The result is:

```
extglob         on
ls: cannot access '20[0-9][0-9] Monthly Data - review.xlsx': No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/reports
        zip warning: 20[0-9][0-9] Monthly Data - review.xlsx not found or empty
        zip warning: name not matched: 20[0-9][0-9] Monthly Tables - review.xlsx
```

From the shell, doing

```
ls 20[0-9][0-9]' Monthly Data - review.xlsx' \
    20[0-9][0-9]' Monthly Tables - review.xlsx'
```

Results in

```
'2019 Monthly Data - Review.xlsx'*  '2019 Monthly Tables - Review.xlsx'*
```

What setting am I missing out on to get this to work like it did in ksh93?

Comment: You appear to have `nocaseglob` enabled in your shell, so it matches `Review` when you write `review`. If you want case insensitive matching in your script as well, enable it explicitly

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it! If you put your response as an answer to the question instead of a comment I can upvote it and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename has capital R `Review` while your glob uses lowercase `review`.

Your local shell most likely has `nocaseglob` enabled to do case insensitive globbing. If this used to work on ksh93, it probably had a similar option enabled by default as well.

In bash you have to enable it explicitly in a script with `shopt -s nocaseglob`